# How to create TAP device on boot in CentOS?

Tags: networking, centos

I'd like to have a TAP device ready to use after boot on CentOS 7. But if I create a file `ifcfg-tap0`, I don't know how to fill `DEVICE=` field because there may be no physical device behind it. And I can't find where to specify the mode `tap` in `ifcfg-tap0` file.

What should I do? Can I embed commands in ifcfg-* files to create TAP devices like in Debian?

Comment: Why do you need to have a tap interface ready for use? The following command will create it: `ip tuntap add mytapdevice mode tap user root`.  Easy enough, isn't it?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, I can manually run a script after boot... It's ok but is there any solution like enabling eth-x devices?

Comment: Not that I know of. You are however mistaken about the DEVICE directive: it is just a name, read the note in the green box here, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_network-bridge.html

Answer (score 1):

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-tap0

```
DEVICE=tap0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Tap
```

bring it up with

```
ifup tap0
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro I found the "right" answer after 3 hours of research.

Actually Centos supports tun/tap interface, but for some reason, their is a step missing.

The mechanism lies in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. This mechanism allows you to write custom ifup-xxx and if-down-xxx scripts for custom interfaces.
This finding was enlightened by this post: http://mmc.com.au/pub/internode-tunnel/

Another surprising finding is that the original Centos ifup-eth script actually supports tun/tap interface. Just take a look at it. For both tun/tap devices, the TYPE parameter should be set to 'Tap' (note the capital T). The actual mode is distinguished by DEVICE (the name of the interface). So a tap device should be named as tap100, a tun device should be named as tun100 or something like that.

But that will not automatically bring you tun/tap interface support. The next thing is to create 2*2 symbolic links to the ifup-eth and ifdown-eth script, and name them ifup-tun/ifup-tap and ifdown-tun/ifdown-tap. (This is the missing step! I don't know why Centos does not provide it out of the box.) Then here you go. You have a persistent tun/tap device in Centos.

Here are the ifcfg-tun100 config file. (The 'tun' in the file name dictates that ifup-tun will be called, so be careful).

```
DEVICE=tun100
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Tap
USERCTL=yes
ARPCHECK=no
ARPUPDATE=no
IPADDR=1.1.1.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

The name in the DEVICE field dictates the mode (tun/tap) of the tunnel.
Always use Tap as TYPE. That's the keyword recognized in ifup/down-eth.
Disable ARPCHECK/ARPUPDATE if in tun mode (because it's not supported).
Everything else will be nice and easy.

Comment: Figured out if you name your configure file ifcfg-eth100, and provide the DEVICE with a name of tun100, then no symbolic link is needed.

Comment: Why are you giving two answers?